# True or False: Every closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of disjoint closed intervals up to a measure zero set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Is the following statement true?

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be closed. Then there exist a measure-zero set
$S_0$
and disjoint intervals
$[a_k,b_k],k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\cdots < b_{k-1} < a_k < b_k < a_{k+1} < \cdots$ (with possibly $a_{-\infty} = \infty$ or $b_{\infty} = \infty$ )
such that

\begin{equation*}
S = S_0 \cup \bigsqcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} [a_{k},b_{k}] 
\end{equation*}

An elementary argument or counterexample would be nice, or also a reference if the proof is very involved.

EDIT: It's definitely false, see the comments for examples, like [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)

Comment: Try to show it is false.  You may need to wait until later in a measure theory course.  Such counterexamples should appear in any measure theory textbook.  A hint would be: a closed set of positive measure that has empty interior.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you have a simple counterexample in mind? I tried searching on Google for an answer but couldn't find one. I think it would be nice to have this question up online in case others want to search.

Comment: Any fat Cantor set is a counterexample.

Comment: @Ramiro ... Yes, that is what I had in mind.  But it cannot be considered "simple" for a student beginning to study Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Or much simpler than a fat Cantor set, something like $(-\infty,0]\cup[1/2,1]\cup[1/4,1/3]\cup[1/6,1/5]\cup\dots$

Comment: Thanks these answers are helpful. @EricWofsey thanks that set also works, but the fat Cantor sets are more what I had in mind (in particular, your example is still a countable union of closed intervals).